# PostgreSQL Function Syntax Error in DECLARE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4, sql-function

I am unable to create this function as I get **syntax error near INTEGER** in **line 6**. Am I missing something here?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_application_status_by_token(applicationToken integer, userId integer, newStatus data.applicationstatus)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN
  LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
    DECLARE
      applicationId INTEGER;
    BEGIN
      SELECT id INTO applicationId FROM data.listings_applications WHERE token = applicationToken;
      INSERT INTO public.listings_applications_status(application_id, user_id, status)  VALUES (applicationId, userId, newStatus);
      UPDATE public.listings_applications SET status = newStatus WHERE token=applicationToken;
      RETURN TRUE;
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
    END;
$function$
```

Comment: change `LANGUAGE sql` to `LANGUAGE plpgsql`?..

Comment: worked! Thanks, add your ans below so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a PL/pgSQL function, so you must declare it as such.

Use

```
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

rather than

```
LANGUAGE sql
```

Answer (score 1):

change

`LANGUAGE sql`

to

`LANGUAGE plpgsql`

to make it work. [SQL DECLARE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-declare.html) is for cursors. In your function it is `plpgslq` command